# Efficient Way to do global ranking on a large amount of data in Pyspark

Tags: sorting, pyspark, ranking

I am trying to do global rank on a large amount of data using Pyspark.

I searched online and found many answers used window:

```
window_rank = Window.orderBy(F.asc('score'))
scores_df = scores_df.withColumn('rank', F.row_number().over(window_rank))
```

However, this method seems shuffled all the data into one worker node, and thus, it is not optimal for large volume of data.

Is there a distributed way to do ranking task in Pyspark?

Comment: Do you think that is possible? How can you rank the data between several nodes?

Comment: It sounds like ranking the data between several nodes would be theoretically possible, but that would take **a lot** more computation than bringing all the nodes together.

Comment: Do you have approximate method?